# What is the cron definition for each minute for a job in grails?

Tags: grails, cron, quartz-scheduler, jobs

I'm using Quartz plugin for Grails for a synchronized job minute by minute, but I'm unable to use the `0 * * * * *` definition and is throwing some exception:

> Error loading plugin manager: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class grails.plugins.quartz.DefaultGrailsJobClass (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cron expression '0  *  *  *  *  *' in the job class cl.ionix.softoken.jobs.SendRefreshStatusByMinuteJob is not a valid cron expression

What can be the correct cron expression to execute every minute?

Comment: You can always use:
http://www.cronmaker.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
0 0/1 * * * ?
```

According to the [doc](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/scheduling.html)

> Either Day-of-Week or Day-of-Month must be "?", or you will get an
>   error since support by the underlying library is not complete. So you
>   can't specify both fields, nor leave both as the all values wildcard
>   "*"; this is a departure from the unix crontab specification.

Answer (score 0):

This is the cron expression that triggers in every minute:

```
0 0/1 * * * *
```

docs: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger